# How to get the line height of a QTextBlock?

Tags: c++, qt

Windows 7 SP1
MSVS 2010
Qt 4.8.4

Given this code:

```
#include <QTGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QTextDocument* text_document = new QTextDocument("testing");
    QTextBlock text_block = text_document->begin();
    qDebug() << text_block.text() << text_block.blockFormat().lineHeight()
             << text_block.blockFormat().lineHeightType();
}
```

The console displays:

```
"testing" 0 0
```

**Question**: Why doesn't lineHeight return "the LineHeight property for the paragraph"? The lineHeightType is set for single spacing.

I am clearly not understanding this. When I try to set the line height before outputting, nothing happens (lineHeight() is still zero):

```
text_block.blockFormat().setLineHeight(30,QTextBlockFormat::SingleHeight);
```

To be clear, in my application  nothing happens when outputting to a GUI window.

Even trying:

```
 qDebug() << text_block.text() << text_block.layout()->boundingRect().height();
```

gives me zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got lineHeight to work but this does:

```
int CalculateLineHeight(QTextBlock text_block)
{
    int max_ascent  = 0;
    int max_descent = 0;
    int max_leading = 0;

    // A fragment is a piece of the text block with the the same format, such as font.
    for (QTextBlock::Iterator fragment_it = text_block.begin(); !(fragment_it.atEnd()); ++fragment_it)
    {
        QTextFragment fragment = fragment_it.fragment();
        QTextCharFormat fragment_format = fragment.charFormat();
        QFont fragment_font = fragment_format.font();
        QFontMetrics fragment_font_metrics (fragment_font);
        max_ascent  = std::max(fragment_font_metrics.ascent(), max_ascent);
        max_descent = std::max(fragment_font_metrics.descent(),max_descent);
        // Find the leading of the font with the maximum height. If more than
        // one, then find the largest lead among them.
        if ( current_height > max_height )
        {
            max_height = current_height;
            max_leading = current_leading;
        }
        else if ( current_height == max_height && current_leading > max_leading )
        {
            max_leading = current_leading;
        }
    }
    return max_ascent + max_descent + max_leading + 1; // + 1 for the baseline
}
```

You may think the answer is max height() but fonts with the same height may have different ascents, descents and leadings.

Comment: Now, with my change, it works properly. I just needed to account for the leading in the largest font.

Comment: This doesn't work when a `QTextFragment` stretches more than one line (Qt 5.9)

Answer (score 0):

Is this done before or after the widgets have had their show() function called?  IE, are they visible?  I have never used QTextBlock before, but I have found that until everything is visible (or maybe until the event loop is kicked off), I cannot trust the sizes of QWidgets.  This is true in main().

For debugging purposes, I would check them after the application is running.

Comment: Before. This is part of the pre-processing I am doing before it displays. In other words, I need this information to create the window. To be clear, this programming wasn't being done in main() -- I just shrunk it down to its barest essentials. I will play around with it and see if post-show will give me access. But every other widget I've worked with does give me access to its methods and properties.

Comment: No, did not make a difference. I appreciate the idea. :)